# Trying to retrieve property of object

Tags: php

I've got an object:

```
{
"id": "132268893498013",
"name": "The Flavel",
"location": {
"street": "",
"city": "Paignton",
"state": "",
"country": "United Kingdom",
"zip": "",
"latitude": 50.3520464135,
"longitude": -3.57920113147
},
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Flavel/132268893498013",
"website": "http://www.theflavel.org.uk",
"phone": "01752 924008"
}
```

I can retrieve this object with:

```
return $pages['data'][0]
```

i.e. it's the first object in the `data` array. And I'm trying to retrieve the `id` with:

```
return $pages['data'][0]->id;
```

But I get the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It means `$pages['data'][0]` is not an object.

Comment: use `$pages['data'][0]['id']` instead

Comment: Could you try a `var_dump` and post it for us? :D

Comment: Which version of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Its a JSON and you need to decode before accessing the data as

```
$json = '{
"id": "132268893498013",
"name": "The Flavel",
"location": {
"street": "",
"city": "Paignton",
"state": "",
"country": "United Kingdom",
"zip": "",
"latitude": 50.3520464135,
"longitude": -3.57920113147
},
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Flavel/132268893498013",
"website": "http://www.theflavel.org.uk",
"phone": "01752 924008"
}';

$data = json_decode($json,true);

echo $data["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Daan mentioned in the comment, it isn't an object, looks like it could be an array, try

```
return $pages['data'][0]['id'];
```